# how to limit allowed formatting options in hallo.js rich text editor

Tags: wagtail, hallo-js

I want to limit the formatting options for the wagtail.wagtailcore.fields.RichTextField field. For example, how to limit the user so that he can only use bold, paragraph and links in the RichTextField. I found examples for extending the editor, but not for limiting.

Comment: This discussion might help: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wagtail/PERl4ffbkiE/mmA4-OhACgAJ

Comment: this is now obsolete, with the new draftail editor its build-in see [wagtail editing_interface](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit options for RichTextField in wagtail by using keyword [features](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#limiting-features-in-a-rich-text-field) as follows.

`body = RichTextField(features=['bold','link'])`

The list of all the available features are as follows:

- h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 - heading elements
- bold, italic - bold / italic text
- ol, ul - ordered / unordered lists
- hr - horizontal rules
- link - page, external and email links
- document-link - links to documents
- image - embedded images
- embed - embedded media (see [Embedded content](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/embeds.html#embedded-content))

Example and detail description can be found in it's [official site](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/embeds.html#embedded-content).